# Prepend each bash command with string

Tags: bash, shell

I have a set of commands that starts the same:

- mycommand argument1 argument2 unique:string
- mycommand argument1 argument2 another:string

Is there a way I could modify `.bashrc` so it automatically add the `mycommand argument1 argument2` before I execute each command?

Comment: You could do this with a DEBUG trap intercepting and modifying commands that are run. That is not at all to say, though, that it's anything resembling a good idea.

Comment: What's the real-world use case here? Does it really make sense to be running a general-purpose shell?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can I create, for example, a "subshell"? Super newbie here, been trying to search for a solution before but out-of-the-box solution would save a lot of time today, before I jump into how to properly do it

Comment: ...yes, of course -- any time you use `( ... )` or `$( ... )` or pipelines you're creating a subshell. But what I really meant to refer re: "a general-purpose shell" is an unrestricted copy of bash (as opposed to something like `rbash`, or a custom shell written in a completely different programming language -- Python has tools for creating them in the standard library f/e)

Comment: [The Python `cmd` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) is one example of a toolkit for creating custom shell-like interfaces. Whether it's appropriate depends entirely on your use case -- _why_ you're doing this, if there are security constraints that are supposed to be enforced, etc. (Python also has the `shlex` module, which provides POSIX shell-like parsing for quotes/escapes/etc)

Comment: Anyhow -- _if_ you were trying to do this as a security mechanism (where `mycommand` filters which commands can be run, or causes things to be run in a "safe" environment), it's likely not to be very effective. `mycommand argument1 argument2 unique:string >~/.bashrc`, for example, will empty out `~/.bashrc` so if the user logs and back in they'll be in an unrestricted shell. And that's just the first, simplest thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Seems it will be far easier in this case to look into the Python module you provided – thanks!